# How to filter table across groups and their content

Tags: mysql, sql, select, filter

In my table are orders of items has to be produced (in my example simplyfied).
I have to filter only those orders which are completely done. Orders are done, if status of all orders (with same order_id) is '4' or '-1'.

```
"id"    "order_id"  "item_nr"   "status"
"689"   "4"         "M2223"     "3"
"690"   "4"         "K3224"     "-1"
"691"   "4"         "X1837"     "4"
"692"   "4"         "M2338"     "0"
"693"   "5"         "E7273"     "4"
"694"   "5"         "E8883"     "-1"
"695"   "5"         "B9217"     "4"
"696"   "5"         "B2662"     "4"
```

In the example case: i want to get the result:

```
"693"   "5"         "E7273"     "4"
"694"   "5"         "E8883"     "-1"
"695"   "5"         "B9217"     "4"
"696"   "5"         "B2662"     "4"
```

How to the select this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to `LEFT JOIN` your table to a subquery which identifies all *non* matching orders, and then retain only records from orders which do not match.  This implies that those matching orders do not have any records with an incomplete status.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT order_id
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE status NOT IN ('4', '-1')
) t2
    ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id
WHERE t2.order_id IS NULL
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Per the comment by @shadow we could also phrase this query using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.status NOT IN ('4', '-1') AND t2.order_id = t1.order_id
)
```

Comment: [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d78bb/1) is a sqlfiddle with the expected result with Tim's query.

Comment: Using not exists insted of not in would probably speed it up. I like the explanation, so gets my vote.

Comment: @Shadow I gave an update with `NOT EXISTS`.  To be honest, I don't use this very often, but maybe I should research the performance benefits of using this in MySQL.